# React Native - google map image link that opens google maps app

Tags: react-native, google-maps

In my React Native app, I need to generate a static google maps image with a dynamic address (like the image below). Once you press on the image, it needs to open up the google maps app to that same address. I looked at react-native-maps and it seems like overkill for what I want to achieve... Is there a way to embed a static google maps image in the app, put it inside a TouchableOpacity and just open google maps once you press on it?

[image: Example of static google maps image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use The Maps Static API to get the image

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

and  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-open-maps to open the map app.

i hope you got your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just checked the google maps static api. It's not a free service? Looks like it's 2$ per 1k requests. Anything cheaper out there?